# How do I turn off window maximization when reaching the edge of the screen in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, gui, aero, aero-snap

The title sums it up, pretty much. I tend to arrange windows on the screen manually, and when I bring a window too far up it automatically maximizes itself. How do I turn this off? It drives me nuts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are step by step instructions from How-To Geek, "[Disable Aero Snap](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/disable-the-mouse-drag-window-arranging-feature-in-windows-7/)."

Short version: Go to the control panel -> Ease of Use Center. Click "Change how your mouse works". Un-check “Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen” and hit Apply.